# binding a single image to different image tags in my wpf C# app doesnt work

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0

xaml code:

```
    <Image x:Name="image2" Margin="-700 -10 0 0"/>
```

and in second image tag I've tried to reference to the image defined above:

```
    <Image x:Name="image2" />
```

c# code:

```
    private ImageSource image =
    new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.jpg"));
    image2.Source = image;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way to go about this. first in the code behind i used a class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` then bound the image controls as follows:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Logo}" />
```

to a property that returns an `ImageSource` as follows:

```
 private ImageSource logo = null;
    public ImageSource Logo
    {
        get
        {
            return logo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value!=logo)
            {
                logo = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Logo");
            }
        }
    }
```

then i set the image as follows :

```
 private ImageSource image =
    new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/logo.jpg"));
c.Logo=image;
```

now every time i bind the image control to this property the same image is displyed instead of creating two image controls:

```
<Image x:Name="image1"/>
<Image x:Name="image2"/>
```

then assign to each control the same image as

```
 var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.jpg"));
image1.Source = bitmap;
image2.Source = bitmap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question. But if it is "*how do I create a BitmapImage in code-behind and assign it to two different Image controls?*", the answer is simple:

Create two Image controls in XAML and give them unique names:

```
<Image x:Name="image1"/>
<Image x:Name="image2"/>
```

In code behind, create a BitmapImage and assign it to each Image's Source property:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/image.jpg"));
image1.Source = bitmap;
image2.Source = bitmap;
```

Comment: And please don't call it "Image tag". It's an Image control.

Comment: this works just fine but would like to avoid having to create so many instances. what i'm trying to achieve is a scenario where a user can create two different reports for two different clients such that the logo and company name would be different for both clients and since the logo appears on every page i want the set the image control of every page to display a logo depending on which client has been selected..trying my best to be clear

Comment: the two different reports share common data so what is really different is the logo and company name